# Problem question for Discrete Maths - methods of proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have trouble understanding what this question is trying to ask me,

"Given that 'n' is a non-negative integer prove that the following 3 statements about 'n' are equivalent.

i.) 3n + 2 is even

...

I haven't found any similar question format as this, but I see the question as,

"If 'n' is a natural number then, 3n + 2 is even."

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that three statements are equivalent, we mean:

Statement 1 if and only if statement 2

Statement 2 if and only statement 3

Statement 1 if and only if statement 3.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Some people consider $\mathbb{N}$ to be $\{1,2,...\}$ while others $\{0,1,2,...\}$ so just to be safe I would write the set of non-negative integers as $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ just to be pedantic about it.